# Какой корень в слове «мальчик»?

Tags: морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

В словаре З. Потихи корень ***-мальч-***, в словаре Тихонова корень ***-мальчик-***.

Answer (score 3):

> В словаре З. Потихи корень ***-мальч-***, в словаре Тихонова корень
> ***-мальчик-***.

И всё же… У Тихонова помимо *"Морфемно-орфографического"*, где действительно отсутствует членение слова "мальчик" на морфемы, есть ещё и другие словари — в частности, *"Словарь-справочник по русскому языку"* (М., 1997), в котором он даёт такой морфемный разбор этого слова:

**непроизв.; маль/чик/ (ср.: мал/ый).**

В сборнике *"Развитие современного русского языка"* (М., 1975) в одной из статей говорилось, что

> …в слове ***мальчик*** раньше было такое членение: мал'-ч-ик, что было
> соотнесено со словом ***малец*** (при чередовании: э — — 0 и /ц/
> —/ч/). В современном же русском языке связь ***малец — мальчик***
> оборвалась, и в лучшем случае здесь членение идёт так: *мал'-чик*).

Такого членения (***маль/чик***) придерживался и *"Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь*" Панова и Текучева (М., 1985). Такое же членение приводил когда-то и Виноградов в своей книге *"Русский язык. Грамматическое учение о слове"*…

Более понятным в настоящее время кажется выделение в слове ***мальчик*** (как и в однокоренных с ним словах ***мальч**ишка, **мальч**онка, **мальч**онок, **мальч**уган*) корня "***мальч***".

Такой корень выделяют в слове ***мальчик*** словари Потихи, такой корень выделяет и ряд других словарей — в частности, *"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка"* под ред. В.В. Морковкина (М., 2016).

Answer (score 2):

Это не совсем моя тема, но всё-таки у меня есть вопросы к первому ответу.

Я сомневаюсь, что в этом слове корень **МАЛ**, скорее здесь верна информация из  словаря Тихонова: **корень "мальчик".**

Надо хотя бы дать **определение корня**.
Допустим, это  наименьшая общая часть родственных слов, передающая его основное значение.

МАЛ – это действительно наименьшая общая часть исторически родственных слов, но вот значение слов ***маленький*** и ***мальчик***  в современном языке не совпадают. Прилагательное ***маленький*** может даже определять существительное ***мальчик***: маленький мальчик.

Слово ***малый*** в словаре также отодвинули на задний план, оно чаще употребляется в краткой форме. Теперь на непроизводное слово с основным значением  «небольшой» больше претендует  прилагательное ***маленький***.

МАЛЬЧИК,  м. 1. Ребёнок, подросток мужского пола.

МАЛЕНЬКИЙ, 1. Незначительный по величине, размерам (противоп.: большой). М-ая комната. М. стол.  // Невысокого роста. (противоп.: высокий). М. человек. **М. мальчик.**  М-ая лошадка.

Что касается формального словообразования, то верно  **мал/ец –  мальч/ик**, здесь суффикс  ИК, а не ЧИК. Суффикс ЧИК используется для образования существительных от существительных.

"Малец" и "мальчуган" (в современном языке) образуются от слова "мальчик" **при усечении основы**, это его стилистические варианты: МАЛЕЦ,  м. Разг. Мальчик, подросток.

**А история** такая:  «малый»  известно с XI  века, «маленький» – с XVII века, а «мальчик» (в форме *малчик*)  зафиксировано в словаре в 1731 году.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Разыскала я старый словарь Тихонова (1978 год), где слова расположены **по гнездам.** Там всё **убедительно** выглядит.

Обозначены два гнезда: ***малый и мальчик***. Это непроизводные основы, в них суффикс не выделяется.

Далее от ***малый*** образуются слова с корнем **МАЛ**: маленький, мало, малыш, малютка, умалить, а также сложные слова (малолюдный, маломощный).

От ***мальчик*** образуются слова с корнем **МАЛЬЧ**: мальчишка, мальчонка, мальчишеский и т.д.

Comment: Sharon, я думаю, что лучше не вмешивать обсуждение сайта в ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо,  удаленный риторический  вопрос к участникам форума я перенесла на Мету.

Comment: В печатном издании 1990 года (А. Н. Тихонов. Словообразовательный словарь русского языка) такое же деление: 68. **ма́л** (ый) I, _прил._; ма́л-**ый** II, _сущ._ 72. **ма́льчик** _ср._ малый I—II.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова и Sharon, в **словообразовательных** словарях Тихонов не приводит морфемное членение **непроизводных** слов, но это не говорит о том, что все эти слова он считает состоящими только из корня! И потому с утверждением в ответе Sharon, что «в непроизводных основах суффикс не выделяется» Тихонов, если бы это утверждение услышал, вряд ли бы согласился. Скорее бы, категорически не согласился!

Comment: Может быть, и не согласился бы, я не знаю, но вы-то, вероятно, знаете. Так почему в непроизводных основах категорически надо что-то выделять. Вероятно, новый корень и усекаемую часть основы, только зачем? И как тогда узнать, что основа непроизводная?  В современном языке суффикс ИК не участвует в образовании этого слова (оно образовалось давно, это уже история), а можно подумать, что участвует.  Вот так и создается мешанина, неопределенность, неоднозначность с красивым названием  (вы знаете каким).

Comment: @Sharon: _В современном языке суффикс ИК не участвует в образовании этого слова (оно образовалось давно, это уже история)_ === Открою Вам маленький секрет: слово «девочка» тоже образовалось давно, и слово это тоже при словообразовательном анализе считается непроизводным, но всё это не говорит о том, что суффикс в нём (при морфемном анализе) не выделяется.

Comment: Может быть, может быть, в Сети чего только не увидишь. Написано, что способ образования слова суффиксальный и выделен суффикс ОЧК. Это теперь у наших грамматиков означает, что основа непроизводная? И кстати, если слова разбираются по-разному, то о чем это говорит? О женской дискриминации, о непоследовательности решений? Или в этом есть глубокий, но тайный смысл, понятный только посященным.

Answer (score 2):

Меня заинтересовали **разные подходы** при морфемном разборе. Я полагаю, что разбор должен относиться именно к современному состоянию языка, а историческое словообразование — это особая тема, где учитываются этимологические данные.

А вот **разным решениям** при разборе  можно попробовать дать оценку, так как возможность для этого предоставляется хорошая: у нас для одного слова ***мальчик*** три разных варианта.

**1. Маль/чик**

Преимущества

А) Морфемы легко **узнаваемы** для пользователей: корень МАЛ имеет значение **маленькой** величины, причем это именно **наименьший** формант с таким значением. Суффикс ЧИК имеет **уменьшительно-ласкательное** значение.

Б) Также МАЛ — это **исторический** корень, который выделяется в слове *мал/ый*.

Недостатки

А) Слова ***мальчик*** и ***малый*** в современном языке относятся к разным словообразовательным гнездам, так как ***мальчик***  по толковому словарю уже не определяется семантикой корня МАЛ, а имеет другое значение (подросток мужского пола).

Б) Непроизводный характер основы **не обозначен**.

В) Деление на морфемы **не соответствует** словообразовательной схеме, в действительности она выглядит так: *мал/ый – мал/ец – маль/ч/ик*.

Г) При разборе родственных слов ***мальчонка, мальчишка*** неясно, что делать **со звуком Ч**.

**2. Мальч/ик**

Преимущества

Выделен корень МАЛЬЧ, **общий** для родственных слов.

Недостатки

**Не обозначен** непроизводный характер основы.

**3. Мальчик** (нет деления на морфемы)

Преимущества

Слово мальчик рассматривается как **непроизводное**, образующее новое словообразовательное гнездо, что соответствует действительности.

Недостатки

Такое решение не кажется очевидным и всем понятным, так как  все родственные слова имеют корень МАЛЬЧ, поэтому при их образовании исходная основа  **усекается** на формант ИК.

**Вывод**

Наиболее подходящим представляется **вариант 3**. В нем обозначен **непроизводный** характе  основы, а это **наиболее важная характеристика**.

Усечение же основы при словообразовании происходит довольно часто, здесь нет особой трудности для понимания.

Наибольшее количество недостатков **у варианта 1**, что делает его **неприемлемым**.

Answer (score 0):

"Мальчик" не может быть корнем, - однокоренные слова "малец" и "мальчуган" исключают это. Здесь "чик" является уменшительно-ласкательным суффиксом. Примеры: палец - пальчик, заяц - зайчик.
Мальчик происходит от малый - маленький человек, следовательно корень у того слова будет "мал".

Comment: В слове ЗАЯЦ исправьте, пожалуйста, описку.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина!

Answer (score 0):

Нет однозначного ответа на ваш вопрос.
Для школьной практики лучше, думаю, следовать Тихонову и выделять корень ***мальчик*** бех дальнейшего разложения.

По поводу отсутвия однозначного ответа.
Во-первых, в русском языке существует такое понятие, как морфемное переразложение. Об этом - см. slava1947. Мне остается только добавить, что этот процесс породил и несколько походов к морфемному анализу, построенных на различных аспектах лингвистического учения. Прежде всего это так называемые синхронический подход (рассматривает слово как есть, в его живом состоянии) и диахронический (противопоставляет первому всю историческую морфемную грамматику). Словари, в частности те, о которых вы говорите, исповедуют разные подходы, школьные словари (Тихонов прежде всего) тяготеют именно к синхроническому подходу, школьникам не так важно знать, как и от чего появился современный морф, им для практического пользования надо понять каким этот морф стал сейчас - чтобы воспользоваться школьными правилами. И в этой ситуации Тихонов вполне справедливо рассматривает "мальчик" как неделимую корневую "ячейку", поскольку связь с ранее бывшими однокоренными словами совершенно непрозрачна для школьника.

Ну и во-вторых. Словари эти разного времени. За это время могла измениться сама методика преподавания и объяснения. Тихонов со всеми правками и переизданиями сейчас представляется более актуальным для всех школьных вопросов. То есть для практических школьных надобностей разумно считать корнем именно ***мальчик***, без разложения на морфемы. Хотя тут есть и подводные камни. Суффикс -ик- хорошо известен школьникам, поэтому желание сократить корень до ранее выделяемого "мальч" (как у Потихи) вполне естественно.